# what thickener has the most waxy consistency?

Tags: cheese, thickening

for nutcheese recipes.

Have tried 
guar and xanthan  -slimy;
tapioca -gooey
Kappa -gelatin firm

really looking for an edam waxy consistency:
shall I try harder fats like cacao butter or is there a waxier thickener?

cheers,
Pat

Answer (score 3):

If you’re looking into hydrocolloids, the best you can get will be a iota (0.45%) and kappa (0.35%) gel, which is used to coat food with a firm gel.

I think you’re thinking into the right direction in getting a real waxy texture will go through exploring lipids and lipcolloids (I don’t really know if there are food applications though).

Comment: Try mixing them ;)